# Changing the encoding in the entire project when you press the key. VS Code

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-code

```
 "command":"workbench.action.editor.changeEncoding"},
```

Opens only the menu for changing the encoding.

Comment: Maybe you can use extension [Command on All Files](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.commandOnAllFiles)

Comment: encoding depends on the file extension or the file association in the `settings.json`, this can be in `.vscode` folder of the workspace

Comment: This should be done when the key is pressed.

Comment: the languageID is not fixed to the file, if the file is not opened you can't set the languageID, you have to change the extension or a setting, AFAIK VSC has no comment line to set the languageID